# ActionbarSherlock implementation in Android Studio

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to include ActionbarSherlock in my project following this tutorial http://showlabor.blogspot.ca/2013/05/actionbarsherlock-in-android-studio-01.html but i get the following error:

```
Gradle: Execution failed for task ':libraries:ActionBarSherlock:actionbarsherlock:compileReleaseAidl'.
> Could not call IncrementalTask.taskAction() on task ':libraries:ActionBarSherlock:actionbarsherlock:compileReleaseAidl'
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: time to switch to ActionBar Compat in the android support v7 library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally ended up switching to ActionBarCompat as suggested and everything worked as expected.